# How to replace values in a JSON dictionary with their respective shell variables in jq?

Tags: json, shell, environment-variables, jq

I have the following JSON structure:

```json
{
  "host1": "$PROJECT1",
  "host2": "$PROJECT2",
  "host3" : "xyz",
  "host4" : "$PROJECT4"
}
```

And the following environment variables in the shell:

```sh
PROJECT1="randomtext1"
PROJECT2="randomtext2"
PROJECT4="randomtext3"
```

I want to check the values for each key, if they have a "$" character in them, replace them with their respective environment variable(which is already present in the shell) so that my JSON template is rendered with the correct environment variables.

I can use the `--args` option of jq but there are quite a lot of variables in my actual JSON template that I want to render.

I have been trying the following:

```sh
jq 'with_entries(.values as v | env.$v)
```

Basically making each value as a variable, then updating its value with the variable from the env object but seems like I am missing out on some understanding. Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

*EDIT*

Thanks to the answers on this question, I was able to achieve my larger goal for a part of which this question was asked

- iterating over each value in an object,
- checking its value,

  - if it's a string and starts with the character "$"

    - use the value to update it with an environment variable of the same name .
  - if it's an array

    - use the value to retrieve an environment variable of the same name
    - split the string with "," as delimiter, which returns an array of strings
    - Update the value with the array of strings

```
         
jq 'with_entries(.value |= (if (type=="array") then (env[.[0][1:]] | split(",")) elif (type=="string" and startswith("$")) then (env[.[1:]]) else  . end))'
```

Comment: The template as shown is not quite valid as JSON because of $PROJECT4. Please clarify and correct either the description or the template.

Comment: My bad, corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `export` the Bash variables to be seen by `jq`:

```sh
export PROJECT1="randomtext1"
export PROJECT2="randomtext2"
export PROJECT4="randomtext3"
```

Then you can go with:

```sh
jq -n 'with_entries((.value | select(startswith("$"))) |= env[.[1:]])'
```

and get:

```json
{
  "host1": "randomtext1",
  "host2": "randomtext2",
  "host3": "xyz",
  "host4": "randomtext3"
}
```

Comment: Yup that works! Thanks a lot. Could you explain what happens with `env[]` ? Does it create an array out of the `env` object? I was stuck at this.
Also, what if one of the values is an array? the filter seems to fail since it expects only string values.

Comment: `env` outputs an object representing jq's current environment. As with any object you can access a field (which represents an environment variable) using e.g. `env.PROJECT2`. This is (still as with any object) equivalent to using `env.["PROJECT2"]`. Instead of a literal string I used all but the first character `.[1:]` (stripping off the `$` character) of the input/context, which due to the update operator `|=` is the left hand side's value, i.e. the content of the field to be updated (a `select`ed `.value`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got the splicing part, however, using `env.["PROJECT2"]` instead of `env.PROJECT2` doesn't seem to work. `env[]` will return all the values of the variables as per my understanding. Is is the `[]` in `env[]` acting as a grouping container here? Just want to understand this part right.

Comment: Sorry, it should read `env["PROJECT2"]`. And `.[]` alone (or `env[]` in this case) converts an array or an object into a stream of its values.

Comment: Yup, that's what got me confused. I thought that `env[]` gives me a stream of values, how can I refer to the value from there then.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a large number of shell variables might not be such a good idea and does not address the problem of array-valued variables. It might therefore be a good idea to think along the lines of printing the variable=value details to a file, and then combining that file with the template. It’s easy to do and examples on the internet abound and probably here on SO as well. You could, for example, use `printf` like so:

```
printf "%s\t" ${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}
3   2   57  1
```

You might also find `declare -p` helpful.

See also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#arbitrary-strings-as-template-variables

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing me out to that resource. I tried it out and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that replaces all variables in the file regardless of their nesting level. It keeps the values as they are if they are not defined in the environment. In the following example STREET is not defined as environment variable and therefore remains unchanged.

The matching regex (^\$[A-Z_-]+$) can be changed to match your needs, e.g. variables defined with ${} or {{}}.

```
$ cat test.json
{
  "name": "$NAME",
  "address": [{
    "street": "$STREET",
    "other": "$not_matching"
  }]
}

$ cat test.json | NAME=Joe jq 'walk( if type == "string" and test("^\\$[A-Z_-]+$") then . |= env[.[1:]] // . else . end )'
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "address": [
    {
      "street": "$STREET",
      "other": "$not_matching"
    }
  ]
}
```

The only limitation is that it only replaces full matched values. It will not work with a value like `https://$HOSTNAME/index.html`. For this use `sed` instead.